# Hadoop not able to run program

Tags: java, hadoop

Hi This is my first program with hadoop and I have modified wordcount program. I m not able to execute this program. I have changed map output & reducer input to `<text text>`. Input file contains record as `email gender age 21`. Execution hangs up showing `Map 100% Reduce 100%`.

```
//MAPPER
public class WordMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
    Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
      OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOException {
    String s = value.toString();
    String s1;
    Matcher m2;
    FileSplit filesplit = (FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit();
    String fileName = filesplit.getPath().getName();

    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s+email\\s+gender\\s+age\\s+(\\S+)$");
    m2=p1.matcher(s);
    if (m2.find()){
        s1 = m2.replaceFirst("omitted");
        output.collect(new Text(s1), new Text(fileName));
    }
  }
}

    //REDUCER
public class SumReducer extends MapReduceBase implements
    Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

  @Override
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOException {

    int cliCount = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
      cliCount += 1;
    }
    output.collect(key, new IntWritable(cliCount));
  }
}

    //MAIN
public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.printf(
          "Usage: %s [generic options] <input dir> <output dir>\n", getClass()
              .getSimpleName());
      ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.out);
      return -1;
    }

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName(this.getClass().getName());

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    conf.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);

    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    return 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }
}
```

Update:
Only inside _log folder `.xml` file is present

I kept the program executing, hadoop killed it.

```
3/06/19 15:02:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=258875392
13/06/19 15:02:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormatCounter
13/06/19 15:02:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     BYTES_READ=26
13/06/19 15:02:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1322)
    at WordCount.run(WordCount.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Comment: are you not getting your part-r-0001 file in your output directory??

Comment: No. Output hangs at `13/06/19 14:17:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/06/19 14:17:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
`. I have to break the execution using `ctrl+c`. Also this file `clioutput/_temporary/_attempt_201306191122_0002_r_000000_0/part-00000` is empty.

Comment: can you also paste your log files

Comment: I have update the question. Only conf.xml is present at `clioutput/_logs/history/localhost_1371655349840_job_201306191122_0004_conf.xml` Do you want its output.

Comment: As appears from IO Exception, may be the input files are not read. Are you sure input files exists on HDFS and are readable. I would write a simple code first to make sure that I can read input files

Comment: Yes that would be very helpful. I can see the input dir content as `$hadoop fs -ls /user/training/input
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 training supergroup         26 2013-06-18 22:17 /user/training/input/config.txt
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem in reducer. Iterator is not moving ahead because of wrong implementation.

```
    while (values.hasNext()) {
      cliCount += 1;
      //values.next(); This was missing. Adding this runs the code perfectly.
    }
```